# shell script that print lines on a file based on conditions

Tags: shell, if-statement, recursion, line

I've a file like this

```
Name: Test1
Acronym: TEST11
Description: null
Toolkit: false
Tracks:

        List:
                Name: 1st_test
                Acronym: TEST11_1
                Created On: 2016-03-22 15:25:27.355
                Created By: User.9
                Is Default: false
                State: State[Inactive]
                Capability: Capability[Standard]
                No of running instances: 0

                Name: 2nd_test
                Acronym: TEST11_2
                Created On: 2016-03-23 15:07:18.955
                Created By: User.9
                Is Default: true
                State: State[Active]
                Capability: Capability[Standard]
                No of running instances: 0

                Name: 3rd_test
                Acronym: TEST11_3
                Created On: 2016-03-22 11:54:45.276
                Created By: User.9
                Is Default: false
                State: State[Inactive]
                Capability: Capability[Standard]
                No of running instances: 1
```

I need a script that prints Acronym (the one under List) if:

- line "Is Default" = false
- line "State" = Inactive
- line "No of running instances" = 0

From the example file provided I should expect only TEST11_1

Any help will be appreciated.
Regards.

Comment: I believe we have existing Q&A showing how to use awk for this. (Not that one _couldn't_ do it in native bash -- or even native POSIX sh, with more difficulty -- but awk is easier). What does this have to do with recursion?

Comment: Much of this seems to be valid YAML, can you verify this? If so, there are tools for YAML processing. BTW: "shell" is not a programming language but a whole family of languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. One that comes to mind is to use `grep` to parse the file and then loop through each list segment.

Here's a complete example:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob

# name of the file
file=file.txt

# extract the "Name: ..." lines of file
list_names="$(grep -E '\s+Name' "$file")"

list=()

# add each "Name: ..." line to the "list" array
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # trim string
    list+=("${line##*( )}")
done <<< "$list_names"

# check if all three conditions are met
function check {
    grep --quiet --fixed-strings \
        'Is Default: false' <<< "$1" &&
    grep --quiet --fixed-strings \
        'State: State[Inactive]' <<< "$1" &&
    grep --quiet --fixed-strings \
        'No of running instances: 0' <<< "$1"
}

# loop through each list segment and check
# if conditions are met for each one
for f in "${list[@]}"; do
    # select and store all key/value pairs of each instance
    settings="$(grep -A 7 "$f" "$file")"
    # print "Acronym" value if all three strings
    # are found in the check function
    if check "$settings"; then
        output="$(grep 'Acronym' <<< "$settings")"
        # trim string
        echo "${output##*( )}"
    fi
done
```

The output of the script is `Acronym: TEST11_1`, because `TEST11_1` meets all three conditions. The conditions are defined in the `check` function.

I'm not sure if this is clear enough, as the script became a bit verbose. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: This one worked fine. Ty very much

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'[]:[:space:][]+' '
  /^[[:space:]]*$/ {
    if((isDefault == "false") && (instance_count == "0") && (state == "Inactive")) {
        print(acronym)
    }

    acronym=""
    instance_count=0
    isDefault=unknown
    state=unknown
  }
  END {
    if((isDefault == "false") && (instance_count == "0") && (state == "Inactive")) {
        print(acronym)
    }
  }
  /No of running instances:/ { instance_count=$6 }
  /Acronym/ { acronym=$3 }
  /Is Default:/ { isDefault = $4 }
  /State:/ { state=$4 }
'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the input *almost* looks like YAML, we can cheat a little and convert it to actual YAML, then use [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq):

```bash
sed -E 's/ ( Name:)/-\1/' infile \
    | yq '
      .Tracks.List
      | map(
        select(
          .["Is Default"] | not
          and .State == "State[Inactive]"
          and .["No of running instances"] == 0
        )
        | .Acronym
      )
      | .[]
    '
```

The sed command adds a `-` in front of every `Name:` that is preceded by two blanks, and this is likely the most brittle part.

Then, yq drills into `.Tracks.List`, applies the filters, maps to `.Acronym`, and then prints one result per line.

Comment: I'm sure it works but I miss yq command, so I wans't able to test it.